# Disable scrolling and bounce effect on mobile Safari

Tags: scroll, mobile-safari, bounce

I'm working on a browser based app, currently I'm developing and styling for the mobile Safari browser for iPad.

I'm looking for two things: How can I disable vertical scrolling for pages that don't require it? And how can I disable the elastic bounce effect?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

*This answer is no longer state of the art, unless you are developing for a very old iOS device... Please see other solutions*

---

2011 answer: For a web/html app running inside iOS Safari you want something like

```
document.ontouchmove = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

For iOS 5 you may want to take the following into account: [document.ontouchmove and scrolling on iOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798201/document-ontouchmove-and-scrolling-on-ios-5)

Update September 2014:
A more thorough approach can be found here: https://github.com/luster-io/prevent-overscroll. For that and a whole lot of useful webapp advice, see <s>http://www.luster.io/blog/9-29-14-mobile-web-checklist.html</s>

Update March 2016: That last link is no longer active - see https://web.archive.org/web/20151103001838/http://www.luster.io/blog/9-29-14-mobile-web-checklist.html for the archived version instead. Thanks @falsarella for pointing that out.

Comment: I have webapp running inside iOS Safari and I have tried disabling ontouchmove event but it's still possible to see bounce effect if done carefully. (iOS 5)

Comment: @Nilesh: document.ontouchmove is *the* way to do this in iOS Safari.  It is possible, however that some element in your dom is stopping the event propagation from reaching the document element - see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798201/document-ontouchmove-and-scrolling-on-ios-5

Comment: @Nilesh: You might give the ontouchcancel event a go:

Comment: What about just disabling the bounce effect...?

Comment: The problem with this approach is, that scrollable divs in your dom won't scroll anymore. Depending on your dom setup, there are ways around this.

Comment: @huesforalice What are these ways around this that you mention? Is there some way to trigger at which element you want to re-enable the listening?

Comment: Basically what I did was to have a prevent default on the main div inside the body tag. Then I still could have the events on child divs with overflow:scroll correctly scroll. It's a bit fiddly at times to get it completely right, but that approach should work.

Comment: @huesforalice, yes. But scrollable divs are troublesome in iOS in any case - or were at least. We used iScroll (http://iscrolljs.com/) to solve this, which worked great. (Caveat - this was 2011, contents may have shifted during flight)

Comment: @OskarAustegard thanks for the tip Oskar. I'll look into it the next time I face that problem.

Comment: Good one but it completely disables scrolling. what if you have a text box and user touches the text box to open the keyboard (which covers half of the screen height)? you cannot navigate anywhere unless you close the keyboard.

Comment: There's a bunch of people here asking about scrolling divs while using this so.. to make those divs scrollable, add `onTouchMove: function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); e.stopImmediatePropagation(); }`  It'll prevent the event from hitting the body, but the body will remain non-bouncy.  Edit: This is assuming you set $('div').on('touchmove', ...onTouchMove);

Comment: Hi @MattKenefick could you please provide jsfiddle link for the same?

Comment: @OskarAustegard The last link didn't work for me, but I could find the content on web archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20151103001838/http://www.luster.io/blog/9-29-14-mobile-web-checklist.html

Comment: @OskarAustegard It's considered a bad practice to solely provide links in SO answers. Please consider adding the solution itself to the answer.

Comment: @SlavaFominII - really - you're gonna harp on a 3 year old answer that addresses functionality that is long since changed?

Comment: You should see the [Christopher Vickers answer]( https://stackoverflow.com/a/49853392/2294168) ! You need to use `addEventListener('touchmove', (e) => {e.preventDefault()}, { passive: false })`

Comment: I've no idea why you consider this no longer applicable - it's 2023, tested on iPhone X (Latest iOS version) - works like a charm.

Answer (score 127):

You can also change the position of the body/html to fixed:

```css
body,
html {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: This actually worked very well on iPad iOS 8.2 Safari; no bounce effect anymore.

Comment: Doesn't work if you want to place something with position: absolute and all sides set to 0 (to make a fullscreen div) - your whole document shrinks to nothing.

Comment: This seems so logical after all because its the way it should work. I wonder how people come to such solitions haha. Upvoted!

Comment: I'm using a lot of flex boxes, and a lot of other div with position fixed inside the body, and this solution works very well, yet still allow scrolling on div with overflow: scroll effect.

Comment: The page jumps back to the top of the page for me when I use this and then I focus on an input.  Do you know a way around this?

Comment: Works great on iOS 11 on iPhone and iPad.  I love these little perfect fixes.  One line!  Ya can't beat that!  Thanks.

Comment: works on safari but on chrome iOS 66 there's the issue of "pull to refresh" [which you have to prevent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42509310/128511)

Comment: what is the work around for the problem of  jumping back to the top of the page?

Comment: @riv adding width: 100%; height: 100% to both body and html helped me.

Comment: there seems to be an issue, if you scroll outside a scrollable inner window, then ios handles this as you scrolling the page (just you can't tell, as your fixed body is on top of that so you won't see the scrollbars). then there's a timeout until ios thinks you're done scrolling the whole page, until ios thinks that any inner scrollable items aren't scrollable as its still scrolling the whole page in the background. for that reason this isn't usable for me with an inner scrollable window.

Comment: Page can still scroll, you just don't see it happen. Touch move events will be randomly offset

Comment: This doesn't work with PWA

Answer (score 84):

To prevent scrolling on modern mobile browsers you need to add the passive: false. I had been pulling my hair out getting this to work until I found this solution. I have only found this mentioned in one other place on the internet.

```js
function preventDefault(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}

function disableScroll(){
    document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', preventDefault, { passive: false });
}
function enableScroll(){
    document.body.removeEventListener('touchmove', preventDefault);
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. You can see the explanation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener after Chrome 54 touchmove defaulted passive to true which means preventDefault calls would be ignored. That's why you must pass {passive: false}, so the preventDefault call is not ignored.

Comment: You’re declaring the function in JS - But how do you call this function on an element so it works as suggested?

Comment: This works great if you want to disable all kinds of scrolling. But what if I only want to disable scroll on body and keep possibility to scroll on an element with `overflow-y: scroll`? For example, having a modal with a taller view height than body.

Comment: Correct, this solution does stop the rubber band effect but also kills a scroll of the content when it has overflow. Did anyone solve that?

Answer (score 9):

css `overscroll-behavior` is now supported in iOS 16. If you are targeting > iOS 16 devices, to prevent elastic bounce effect, add the following CSS to the html root

```
html {
  overscroll-behavior: none;
}
```

Please note, the solution provided only disables elastic bounce effect when content is larger than viewport.

If you also want to completely disable scrolling in main page on iOS devices, use

```
html body {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use this jQuery code snippet to do this:

```
$(document).bind(
      'touchmove',
          function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
          }
);
```

This will block the vertical scrolling and also any bounce back effect occurring on your pages.

Comment: This is not Javascript, it's jQuery. You should mention that, not everybody is using that framework.

Comment: how can i stop horizontal bounce or scroll

Comment: Horizontal scroll you could even disable it with just css, applying overflow-x:hidden; to your main container. I noticed in the latest versions of safari you cannot disable the bounce effect though. It's a native feature of the browser on mobile devices.

Comment: @inta Just saying this actually is javascript. It's just not pure javascript.

Answer (score 7):

```
overflow: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

On container you can set bounce effect inside element

Source: http://www.kylejlarson.com/blog/2011/fixed-elements-and-scrolling-divs-in-ios-5/

Comment: Together with `overflow:hidden` on the `<body>`, this is still the best solution. However when opening the keyboard or sliding across the screen bottom, it will not work anymore.

Comment: try input  onfocus remove overflow

Answer (score 4):

I know this is slightly off-piste but I've been using Swiffy to convert Flash into an interactive HTML5 game and came across the same scrolling issue but found no solutions that worked.

The problem I had was that the Swiffy stage was taking up the whole screen, so as soon as it had loaded, the document touchmove event was never triggered.

If I tried to add the same event to the Swiffy container, it was replaced as soon as the stage had loaded.

In the end I solved it (rather messily) by applying the touchmove event to every DIV within the stage. As these divs were also ever-changing, I needed to keep checking them.

This was my solution, which seems to work well. I hope it's helpful for anyone else trying to find the same solution as me.

```
var divInterval = setInterval(updateDivs,50);
function updateDivs(){
$("#swiffycontainer > div").bind(
    'touchmove',
     function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
);}
```

Comment: this disables entire scroll in ipad

Answer (score 4):

Code to To remove ipad safari: disable scrolling, and bounce effect

```
   document.addEventListener("touchmove", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }, { passive: false });
```

If you have **canvas** tag inside document, sometime it will affect the usability of object inside Canvas(example: movement of object); so add below code to fix it.

```
    document.getElementById("canvasId").addEventListener("touchmove", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }, { passive: false });
```

Answer (score 3):

none of the solutions works for me. This is how I do it.

```
  html,body {
      position: fixed;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  .the_element_that_you_want_to_have_scrolling{
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
```

Comment: I would do 
.the_element_that_you_want_to_have_scrolling{
      scrolling: touch;
  }

Comment: Your answer worked for me for the html,body but I cannot get "the_element_that_you_want_to_have_scrolling" to scroll. This element is nested inside a few divs that are under body. Does it matter what any of the typical element tags would be for this nested div that I want to have it scroll? I have position: relative.

Comment: This position fixed actually worked for me whilst the JS solution didn't because that killed the scroll of my stages are (sticky header and footer). Having an overflow-y: auto on my stage area allows for scroll so I don't need that webkit directive.

Answer (score 2):

[Try this JS sollutuion](https://gregsramblings.com/2012/05/23/preventing-vertical-scrolling-bounce-using-javascript-on-ios-devices/):

```
var xStart, yStart = 0; 

document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    xStart = e.touches[0].screenX;
    yStart = e.touches[0].screenY;
}); 

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    var xMovement = Math.abs(e.touches[0].screenX - xStart);
    var yMovement = Math.abs(e.touches[0].screenY - yStart);
    if((yMovement * 3) > xMovement) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Prevents default Safari scrolling and bounce gestures without detaching your touch event listeners.

Comment: This stops the web app from scrolling completely on the body element.

Answer (score 2):

improved answer @Ben Bos and commented by @Tim

This css will help prevent scrolling and performance issue with css re-render because position changed / little lagging without width and height

```
html,
body {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%
}
```

Comment: On IOS13, this is the cleanest solution for me, and not yet found any drawbacks...

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using MyScript the Web App and are struggling with the body scrolling/dragging (on iPad and Tablets) instead of actually writing:

`<body touch-action="none" unresolved>`

That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Tested in iphone. Just use this css on target element container and it will change the scrolling behaviour, which stops when finger leaves the screen.

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling

Answer (score 1):

You can use js for prevent scroll:

```
let body = document.body;

let hideScroll = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
};

function toggleScroll (bool) {

  if (bool === true) {
    body.addEventListener("touchmove", hideScroll);
  } else {
    body.removeEventListener("touchmove", hideScroll);
  }
}
```

And than just run/stop  `toggleScroll` func when you opnen/close modal.

Like this  `toggleScroll(true) / toggleScroll(false)`

(This is only for iOS, on Android not working)

Answer (score 1):

Try this JS solution that toggles `webkitOverflowScrolling` style. The trick here is that this style is off, mobile Safari goes to ordinary scrolling and prevents over-bounce — alas, it is not able to cancel ongoing drag. This complex solution also tracks `onscroll` as bounce over the top makes `scrollTop` negative that may be tracked. This solution was tested on iOS 12.1.1 and has single drawback: while accelerating the scroll single over-bounce still happens as resetting the style may not cancel it immediately.

```
function preventScrollVerticalBounceEffect(container) {
  setTouchScroll(true) //!: enable before the first scroll attempt

  container.addEventListener("touchstart", onTouchStart)
  container.addEventListener("touchmove", onTouch, { passive: false })
  container.addEventListener("touchend", onTouchEnd)
  container.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll)

  function isTouchScroll() {
    return !!container.style.webkitOverflowScrolling
  }

  let prevScrollTop = 0, prevTouchY, opid = 0

  function setTouchScroll(on) {
    container.style.webkitOverflowScrolling = on ? "touch" : null

    //Hint: auto-enabling after a small pause makes the start
    // smoothly accelerated as required. After the pause the
    // scroll position is settled, and there is no delta to
    // make over-bounce by dragging the finger. But still,
    // accelerated content makes short single over-bounce
    // as acceleration may not be off instantly.

    const xopid = ++opid
    !on && setTimeout(() => (xopid === opid) && setTouchScroll(true), 250)

    if(!on && container.scrollTop < 16)
      container.scrollTop = 0
    prevScrollTop = container.scrollTop
  }

  function isBounceOverTop() {
    const dY = container.scrollTop - prevScrollTop
    return dY < 0 && container.scrollTop < 16
  }

  function isBounceOverBottom(touchY) {
    const dY = touchY - prevTouchY

    //Hint: trying to bounce over the bottom, the finger moves
    // up the screen, thus Y becomes smaller. We prevent this.

    return dY < 0 && container.scrollHeight - 16 <=
      container.scrollTop + container.offsetHeight
  }

  function onTouchStart(e) {
    prevTouchY = e.touches[0].pageY
  }

  function onTouch(e) {
    const touchY = e.touches[0].pageY

    if(isBounceOverBottom(touchY)) {
      if(isTouchScroll())
        setTouchScroll(false)
      e.preventDefault()
    }

    prevTouchY = touchY
  }

  function onTouchEnd() {
    prevTouchY = undefined
  }

  function onScroll() {
    if(isTouchScroll() && isBounceOverTop()) {
      setTouchScroll(false)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following architecture:

```
<body> <div id="root"></div> </body>
```

this css will  work:

```
#root { position: fixed; height: 100%; overflow: auto; }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working for me. Applying styles to root div instead of body element seems to be the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who don't want to get rid of the bouncing but just to know when it stops (for example to start some calculation of screen distances), you can do the following (container is the overflowing container element):

```
    const isBouncing = this.container.scrollTop < 0 ||
    this.container.scrollTop + this.container.offsetHeight >
        this.container.scrollHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable safari bounce scrolling effect:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with grabbing the html element in the background, when a menu with scroll was open and either at the top or at the bottom at the scroll height. I tried lots of things. Setting html position to `fixed` was the closest I got to lock the screen, but in the PWA it resulted in a white area at the bottom, that I couldn't fix.
Finally I've found a solution, that worked for me :

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    height: calc(100vh - 1px)
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: 'Whatever color you need to hide the 1px at the bottom'
}
```

Because it only seems to be an issue on iOS, I have targeted the devices from iPhone X to 12 Pro Max:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: '#TIP: You can use the color picker from the inspector';

    @media only screen and (min-width: 375px) and (max-height: 926px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {
        height: calc(100vh - 1px);
    }
}
```

This is preventing any kind of scroll, touch or grab in the html or body elements, and scroll is still working in the menu or where else specified. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
   touch-action:none;
}
```

Using JQuery

```
// Disable
$("body").css({ "touch-action": "none" })

// Enable
$("body").css({ "touch-action": "auto" })
```

Answer (score 0):

This CSS solution worked for me (iOS-only, where I found it most annoying):

```
@supports (-webkit-touch-callout: none) {
    html {
        overscroll-behavior-y: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it:

```
let touchMoveBool = false;
function handleTouchMoveEvent(e) {
    if (touchMoveBool) {
        console.log('preventing touchmove');
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default scrolling behaviour including pull down to refresh
    } else {
        console.log('NOT preventing touchmove');
    }
}
    
// Grab the html for an iOS device else grab the body of an android.
if (navigator.platform.match(/iPad|iPhone|iPod/)) {
    document.documentElement.addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMoveEvent, { passive: false });
} else {
    document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMoveEvent, { passive: false });
}
```

Then you just have to toggle the boolean in the section of code that you want/don't-want to be able to scroll or have the scroll behaviour

Answer (score -1):

Similar to angry kiwi I got it to work using height rather than position:

```
html,body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.the_element_that_you_want_to_have_scrolling{
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Comment: as the doc this will enable the bounce also after momentum not disable

Comment: @CaSUaL Not sure what you mean? This solution worked for my use case...

Answer (score -2):

**Solution tested, works on iOS 12.x**

This is problem I was encountering :

```html
<body> <!-- the whole body can be scroll vertically -->
  <article>

    <my_gallery> <!-- some picture gallery, can be scroll horizontally -->
    </my_gallery>

  </article>
</body>
```

While I scrolling my gallery, the body always scrolling itself (human swipe aren't really horizontal), that makes my gallery useless.

Here's what I did while my gallery start scrolling

```js
var html=jQuery('html');
html.css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
//above code works on mobile Chrome/Edge/Firefox
document.ontouchmove=function(e){e.preventDefault();} //Add this only for mobile Safari
```

And when my gallery end its scrolling...

```js
var html=jQuery('html');
html.css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
document.ontouchmove=function(e){return true;}
```

Hope this helps~