# How to prevent zooming and moving page on mobile browsers?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mobile

As in title, im looking for working scrypt to block zooming and if possible block moving page, it can be JQuery, JavaScript, HTML or even PHP.

I tried 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0>"`
But didnt work. Looking forward for helpful ideas.

Comment: Do you try answers of this article for blocking page moves: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949049/mobile-safari-disable-scrolling-pages-out-of-screen

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your above code should work.
This usually works for me.

```
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

[Here's some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Answer (score 0):

This meta-tags work fine for me.

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Answers to this question discribes how to turn off moving page in safary:
[Mobile Safari: Disable scrolling pages "out of screen"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949049/mobile-safari-disable-scrolling-pages-out-of-screen)

Comment: I don't know it exactly. try it in your project

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `user-scalable=0` attribute.

It should be `user-scalable=no`.

> `user-scalable` -
>   Determines whether or not the user can zoom in and out—whether or not the user can change the scale of the viewport. Set to yes to allow scaling and no to disallow scaling. **The default is `yes`.**
>   Setting user-scalable to no also prevents a webpage from scrolling when entering text in an input field.
>   Available in iOS 1.0 and later.

([*Apple Safari Dev*](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html))

Comment: Thanks you all, zooming seems to be blocked, anyway how can i block moving page? in safari i can drag page and "see" safari "background" how to block moving page?

Comment: @karek there is no way to block that. I believe it's iOS native