# prevent webpage from moving when input is focused

Tags: input, mobile, focus, scrollable

I have the following page where I added the css:

```
body{
   height:100%;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

which stops the page from moving up and down on a mobile device.  However, when I focus on one of the inputs the page can then move around (up and down).  How do I prevent that?

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <title>Login</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <form>
      <input type='text'>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">`

I noticed, you already have it set. But I had the same problem and it was because my meta tag at first didn’t have it initially and when I did implement it, it was messy. I cleaned it up, as above and now it works.
In my case I didn’t like the x-overflow on mobile.
Credit to this article where it states setting the **user-scalable =no**. That is the source of your problem.

[How to prevent zooming and moving page on mobile browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083991/how-to-prevent-zooming-and-moving-page-on-mobile-browsers)