# Page scrolls once the div scroll reaches its end

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

When running my app/webpage on my phone I want the page to not scroll vertically but I do want the div to allow vertical scroll. This works, however once the div reaches the bottom of the scroll it scrolls the whole page.

The code Im using to disable vertical page scrolling:

```
 $(document).bind('touchmove', function (e) {
     if (!$('.scrollable').has($(e.target)).length) e.preventDefault();
});
```

my div generator can append any number of divs inside the div that I want to scroll:

```
      $('#mySelect').append("<div style = 'width:100%; height: 30%; text-align: left; background-color: white; border: 1px solid gray; line-height: 0%' >" +
     "<div style = 'float: left; margin-left: 5%'><p style = ' font-size:" +fontSize+"'>" + username + "</p><p style = 'color: gray; font-size:" +subtext+"'>" +wholeName+"</p></div>    <img style = 'float: right; padding-top: 3%; padding-right: 3%; right: 0; height: 80%;' onclick = addFriend('"+username+"') src = 'addfriend.png'></div>");
```

being appended to the div:

```
 <div id="mySelect" class = "scrollable">
 </div>
```

So pretty much I need to know how to stop vertical scrolling once my "scrollable" div reaches top or bottom. Thanks for any help.

EDIT:  I should have specified this is an appmobi/xdk app that is rendered through html. so its not technically in a browser its just the screens viewport.

Comment: It seems this is more of a device issue than a layout one. Try a different browser maybe?

Answer (score 1):

What if you added this css to your document, so there's nothing to scroll vertical to?

```
html,body{height:100%;overflow-y:hidden}
```

here's an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/XEvGP/

it's untested, so let me know if there're any probs.

**NEW APPROACH**
okay, so it's the browser movement...

This should help if it's ios

[document.ontouchmove and scrolling on iOS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798201/document-ontouchmove-and-scrolling-on-ios-5)

Comment: Its the whole "browser" moving, I should have specified this is an appmobi/xdk app that is rendered through html. so its not technically in a browser its just the screens viewport.

Comment: Right now Im using it on iphone. Im running it through "App Lab" a program that lets it run as if it has already been translated into native ios code and is running without a browser.

Comment: cool, they changed it from ios 4 to 5, and i updated the original answer with a link with a marked answer for how it's done on ios 5.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `overscroll-behavior: contain`.