# Prevent iOS 11.3 overflow bouncing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mobile-safari, ios11.3

I've been making use of the `preventDefault` technique on the `touchmove` event since now, when I noticed it doesn't seem to work anymore on iOS 11.3, for neither Safari, nor Chrome or Firefox:

```
document.ontouchmove = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Has anything changed now in iOS? What's the way of preventing the bouncing at the top or end of the page?

[Reproduction online](https://alvarotrigo.github.io/test/pepe/demo2.html)

[Reproduction online with jQuery](https://alvarotrigo.github.io/test/pepe/demo.html)

Video here:

[image]

Comment: FYI: Can‘t reproduce, iOS 11.3, Chrome, iPhone6s

Comment: Mmmm... that's weird... I'll restart and see.

Comment: Nop, I still can reproduce it.

Comment: okay I tried with safari and I can reproduce

Comment: I've tested it from another phone (iphone 5S) with iOS 11.3 and I can not reproduce it. This is **pretty** weird... because I can reproduce it in mine (iphone 7) in all the named browsers, as well as in other iPhones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was caused by a bug of WebKit. [Bug 182521](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=182521)

Try

```
window.addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}, {passive: false});
```

as a workaround.

Comment: I get "preventBouncing is not defined"

Comment: This disabled the scrolling at all

Answer (score 3):

In addition to gluttonys answer:

`window.addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {event.preventDefault();}, {passive: false} );`

is for me a working solution for the safari bounce issue.

Comment: Yeah, same thing. You can use a passive handler for the touchmove or touchstart and prevent it.

Comment: this works but also locks inside the modal too