# Disable elastic scrolling in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari, osx-lion

I just wanted to **diable the elastic scrolling/bounce effect** in Safari (OSX Lion).

I found the solution to set `overflow: hidden` for body in css, but as expected it only **disables the scrollbar**, so if the website is "longer" than the screen you *won't be able to scroll!*

Any solutions or hints are welcome!
Thanks!

Comment: I’m curious what need there might be for this. Let the system do its thang, is usually my motto.

Comment: It's for single page apps, which are designed to look more like desktop apps I think.

Comment: It's a design decision made without our consent that simply doesn't suit all possible web apps.

Comment: Just make a container within body for all of your content and keep the `overflow:hidden;`?

Comment: Elastic scroll severely interferes with the performance of setTimeout (in Chrome, at least) - if you're doing WebAudio scheduling on-the-fly disabling elastic scroll can reduce the risk of drop-outs.

Comment: Actually, strike that. Even if you disable elastic scrolling setTimeout still misbehaves when scrolling beyond the limit of the page (even if the page content does not move).

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can achieve this more universally by applying the following CSS:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

This allows your content, whatever it is, to become scrollable within `body`, but be aware that the scrolling context where `scroll` event is fired is now `document.body`, not `window`.

Comment: This works not just on Safari, but on Chrome, and probably Firefox as well. Thanks!

Comment: Since applying this CSS will remove momentum scrolling on iOS, don't forget to add **-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch** to the **body** to re-enable momentum scrolling on iOS.

Comment: Works great for disabling bounce, but I'm not able to capture the scroll event on document.body, as such `$(document.body).on("scroll", function() { console.log('scrolling') });` I also can't capture on the scrolling element itself. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, have you tried inspecting which element is actually scrolling? It sounds like another element on the page is scrolling instead of the page body.

Comment: This solved the issue, though I think it's worth noting that I had to change all of my `scroll` event listeners to listen to `document.body` instead of `'window'`.

Comment: Resurrecting this...
This doesn't seem to work on ios 7 (chrome or safari). The body does scroll as expected, but once on an edge html scrolling seem to take over.

Comment: Hmm, I haven't tried this in newest iOS yet. Platform level changes are difficult to override.

Comment: -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; seems to re enable the elastic scrolling. On another note, document.body.scrollTop, window.pageYOffset and window.scrollY don't give the value for how far the page has scrolled anymore after using this solution, they stay at 0. How can I find this?

Comment: Please see @Yisela for why this is a bad hack!

Comment: On iOS 8 Safari, setting this CSS will restrict user entering the minimal-ui.

Comment: Adding this CSS makes the fonts look all fuzzy on Chrome... weird.

Comment: This does not work at all for me.

Comment: Is this solution still supposedly correct? I cannot get it to work on an iPhone 6S with iOS 9.3. @Aintaer, if it does still work for you, can you provide a test page?

Comment: This can not work on ios 10

Comment: best solution https://www.bram.us/2016/05/02/prevent-overscroll-bounce-in-ios-mobilesafari-pure-css/

Comment: This made scrolling on mobile dreadfully slow in my scenario. When you combine all of them including @Bobby suggestion to be 
    html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; }

It should work on iOS

Answer (score 15):

If you use the `overflow:hidden` hack on the `<body>` element, to get back normal scrolling behavior, you can position a `<div>` absolutely inside of the  element to get scrolling back with `overflow:auto`. I think this is the best option, and it's quite easy to implement using only css!

Or, you can try with jQuery:

```
$(document).bind(
'touchmove',
function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
}
);
```

Same in javasrcipt:

```
document.addEventListener(
'touchmove',
function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
},
false
);
```

Last option, check [ipad safari: disable scrolling, and bounce effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768269/ipad-safari-disable-scrolling-and-bounce-effect)

Comment: Thanks, the css workaround works! I hoped that there may be a javascript/jquery solution, because this one isn't working for me. I think this will only work for iOS devices. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The answer is a little convoluted. To target OS X, all you need is overflow: hidden on the html and body element. There is no "touchmove" event for OS X, which is the OS that is being asked about.

Comment: If you're transitioning from jQuery, don't forget

    `document.querySelector('div');`
    `document.querySelectorAll('.someClass');`
    `document.querySelector('#someID');`

Answer (score 12):

`overflow:hidden;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch` won't work well on iOS safari 8.1, as the fixed header will be out of visible area.

[image: gif]

As @Yisela says, the css should be placed on `.container`(the `<div>` below `<body>`). which seems no problem(at leas on safari iOS 8.1)

[image: gif]

I've place the demo on my blog: 
http://tech.colla.me/en/show/disable_elastic_scroll_on_iOS_safari

Comment: The link isn't active anymore :(

Answer (score 12):

I had solved it on iPad. Try, if it works also on OSX.

`body, html { position: fixed; }`

Works only if you have content smaller then screen or you are using some layout framework (Angular Material in my case).

In Angular Material it is great, that you will disable over-scroll effect of whole page, but inner sections `<md-content>` can be still scrollable.

Comment: I must also add `body, html { width: 100%; }` for right render in IE11. :(

Comment: This worked for me also.

Answer (score 5):

I made an extension to disable it on all sites. In doing so I used three techniques: pure CSS, pure JS and hybrid.

The CSS version is similar to the above solutions. The JS one goes a bit like this:

```
var scroll = function(e) {
    // compute state
    if (stopScrollX || stopScrollY) {
        e.preventDefault();              // this one is the key
        e.stopPropagation();
        window.scroll(scrollToX, scrollToY);
    }
}

document.addEventListener('mousewheel', scroll, false);
```

The CSS one works when one is using position: fixed elements and let the browser do the scrolling. The JS one is needed when some other JS depends on window (e.g events), which would get blocked by the previous CSS (since it makes the body scroll instead of the window), and works by stopping event propagation at the edges, but needs to synthesize the scrolling of the non-edge component; the downside is that it prevents some types of scrolling to happen (those do work with the CSS one). The hybrid one tries to take a mixed approach by selectively disabling directional overflow (CSS) when scrolling reaches an edge (JS), and in theory could work in both cases, but doesn't quite currently as it has some leeway at the limit.

So depending on the implementations of one's website, one needs to either take one approach or the other.

See here if one wants more details: https://github.com/lloeki/unelastic

Answer (score 4):

None of the 'overflow' solutions worked for me. I'm coding a parallax effect with JavaScript using jQuery. In Chrome and Safari on OSX the elastic/rubber-band effect was messing up my scroll numbers, since it actually scrolls past the document's height and updates the window variables with out-of-boundary numbers. What I had to do was check if the scrolled amount was larger than the actual document's height, like so:

```
$(window).scroll(
    function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height()) return;
        updateScroll(); // my own function to do my parallaxing stuff
    }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could check if the scroll-offsets are in the bounds. If they go beyond, set them back.

```
var scrollX = 0;
var scrollY = 0;
var scrollMinX = 0;
var scrollMinY = 0;
var scrollMaxX = document.body.scrollWidth - window.innerWidth;
var scrollMaxY = document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;

// make sure that we work with the correct dimensions
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
  scrollMaxX = document.body.scrollWidth - window.innerWidth;
  scrollMaxY = document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
}, false);

// where the magic happens
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  scrollX = window.scrollX;
  scrollY = window.scrollY;

  if (scrollX <= scrollMinX) scrollTo(scrollMinX, window.scrollY);
  if (scrollX >= scrollMaxX) scrollTo(scrollMaxX, window.scrollY);

  if (scrollY <= scrollMinY) scrollTo(window.scrollX, scrollMinY);
  if (scrollY >= scrollMaxY) scrollTo(window.scrollX, scrollMaxY);
}, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yckart/3YnUM/

Comment: This causes heavy flicker on our ipad, while preventing the page to scroll up/down.

Comment: @tomazahlin ...and this is a reason for a *downvote*? Really?!

Comment: Sorry, but the solution itself is not good. It should only be applied to desktop computers. Mobile devices which are quite popular nowadays, have a problem with a method like this. So, I suggest if you can add some sort of check around the code, I guess it would be okay.

Comment: @tomazahlin Sorry, but... The most things here, are just there to explain how something **could** work. All of the most code-examples are not ready-to-use, you have to dive into the code and take the part/s that interests you. If something doesn't fit your needs, dive deeper and fix it (...and maybe, open source it?!)

Answer (score 1):

There are a to of situations where the above CSS solutions do not work. For instance a transparent fixed header and a sticky footer on the same page. To prevent the top bounce in safari messing things and causing flashes on full screen sliders, you can use this.

```
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1) {

        $window.bind('mousewheel', function(e) {

            if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {

                if ($window.scrollTop() < 2) return false;
            } 
        });

    }
```

Comment: userAgent snooping is gross

Comment: I Agree. So maybe offer a fix in this situation?

Comment: All rabbit holes, but the accepted answer is the most spacious one

Answer (score 1):

None of the above solutions worked for me, however instead I wrapped my content in a div (#outer-wrap) and then used the following CSS:

```
body {
   overflow: hidden;
}
#outer-wrap {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
     height: 100vh;
     overflow: auto;
}
```

Obviously only works in browsers that support viewport widths/heights of course.