# Bootstrap scrollspy and no rubber-band bounce

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use twitter bootstrap 3 with scrollspy. Everything works like it should. But I also need to disable the rubber-band/elastic scroll effect which comes in many browsers and devices when you scroll to the bottom of a page.
I can get them to work on their own, but not together.

When both are enabled together, scrollspy is stuck on the bottom most item.

I created a bootply here; http://bootply.com/104169 which shows the problem.
The css rules for html and body is the ones that normally takes away the rubber-band effect, however, not on bootply for some reason. The defect in scrollspy is still shown tho.

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/16327467/452081 a user sais `This allows your content, whatever it is, to become scrollable within body, but be aware that the scrolling context where scroll event is fired is now document.body, not window.`. Which sounds logical, but I still doesn’t get that idea to work.