# prevent scrolling up browser behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, google-chrome

I have an interaction on my website that happens on scroll up and in Chrome on my mac when a user scrolls to the bottom of the page, it bounces up a little bit; and, this triggers the interaction causing an undesired effect.

I don't know if this is an OS X or Chrome thing.

Either way, I don't want the scrolling up to happen when the page has reached the bottom unless the user does it or code does it.

How can I prevent this browser behaviour of scrolling back up slightly when reaching the bottom of a page.

Here is what I have to knowing when the bottom of the page is reached:

`if($(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height())`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like something about OSX, i never see anything like that using chrome in windows, have you tested it in other versions? or another browser?

Answer (score 0):

That's probably the "elastic" scrolling of OSX, also implemented in Chrome for OSX (Safari as well). Maybe try out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16327467/1903366).

Comment: the css solution prevents all scrolling when I tried it. I just want the bounce effect to be stopped, but normal scrolling to still work.

Comment: @gomangomango Hmmm since I dont have OSX I cant really try it out myself. Do you have the website running online so you could send me a link?