# Bouncing once scrollbar on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css

I have a strange issue with the scrollbar of a website which I'm developing right now.

This is the url - testportay.free.bg. When I open the sections with overflowing content (Gallery and the two subsections of about) and when I start scrolling down the scrollbar goes down and then immediately goes to top again and this happens only once. Then it stops bouncing and everything with the scrolling is OK. I thought that it was caused by the "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch" property which I added but it seems like this isn't the cause of the problem. Also I'm not sure if it has any connection but on the mobile version when scrolling down (on iphone for example)  ,once the scroll gets to the bottom of the page, the page bounces once, goes about 40px up(back) by covering the link at the bottom (hiding it) and just sticks at that position without being able to scroll again.

Comment: check this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150191/disable-elastic-scrolling-in-safari

Comment: i have checked with your link @abhi312 its working better

Answer (score 0):

I found what's causing the problem. This script is working properly. BUt strangely it when I scroll the scrollbar is making this bounce

```
   $('.link-today[href^="#"],.link-heritage[href^="#"],.link-to-section[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        var target = this.hash;
        var $target = $(target);

        $('.about-heritage, .about-today,#gallery,#contact').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
    });
```