# How can I get this HTML5 Canvas paint application to work for both touch and mouse events?

Tags: javascript, android, html, html5-canvas

Here is the source code of what I'm trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/3nGtM/

Javascript:

```
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    // get the canvas element and its context
    var canvas = document.getElementById('sketchpad');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // create a drawer which tracks touch movements
    var drawer = {
        isDrawing: false,
        touchstart: function (coors) {
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(coors.x, coors.y);
            this.isDrawing = true;
        },
        touchmove: function (coors) {
            if (this.isDrawing) {
                context.lineTo(coors.x, coors.y);
                context.stroke();
            }
        },
        touchend: function (coors) {
            if (this.isDrawing) {
                this.touchmove(coors);
                this.isDrawing = false;
            }
        }
    };
    // create a function to pass touch events and coordinates to drawer
    function draw(event) {
        // get the touch coordinates
        var coors = {
            x: event.targetTouches[0].pageX,
            y: event.targetTouches[0].pageY
        };
        // pass the coordinates to the appropriate handler
        drawer[event.type](coors);
    }

    // attach the touchstart, touchmove, touchend event listeners.
    canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', draw, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', draw, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('touchend', draw, false);

    // prevent elastic scrolling
    document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }, false); // end body.onTouchMove

}, false); // end window.onLoad
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <canvas id="sketchpad" width="400" height="400">Sorry, your browser is not supported.</canvas>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:Arial;
}
#container {
    position:relative;
}
#sketchpad {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

I tried adding event listeners for mouse down/up/move but those didn't seem to work.

Alternatively, if anyone has any suggestions for open source canvas painting apps that work on computer and tablet I'd rather just use that.

So far the only one that has stood out is https://github.com/PlayMyCode/SkyBrush but it unfortunately doesn't work on android tablets (at least the ones I've been able to try).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the [modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gfcarv/66nVn/)

I added a way to detect when running in a touch device and a switch to map the mouse events to touch events.

Also notice that when touchend occurred we need to use `event.changedTouches` to get the `coors` correctly.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
// get the canvas element and its context
var canvas = document.getElementById('sketchpad');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// create a drawer which tracks touch movements
var drawer = {
    isDrawing: false,
    touchstart: function (coors) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(coors.x, coors.y);
        this.isDrawing = true;
    },
    touchmove: function (coors) {
        if (this.isDrawing) {
            context.lineTo(coors.x, coors.y);
            context.stroke();
        }
    },
    touchend: function (coors) {
        if (this.isDrawing) {
            this.touchmove(coors);
            this.isDrawing = false;
        }
    }
};
// create a function to pass touch events and coordinates to drawer
function draw(event) { 
    var type = null;
    // map mouse events to touch events
    switch(event.type){
        case "mousedown":
                event.touches = [];
                event.touches[0] = { 
                    pageX: event.pageX,
                    pageY: event.pageY
                };
                type = "touchstart";                  
        break;
        case "mousemove":                
                event.touches = [];
                event.touches[0] = { 
                    pageX: event.pageX,
                    pageY: event.pageY
                };
                type = "touchmove";                
        break;
        case "mouseup":                
                event.touches = [];
                event.touches[0] = { 
                    pageX: event.pageX,
                    pageY: event.pageY
                };
                type = "touchend";
        break;
    }        

    // touchend clear the touches[0], so we need to use changedTouches[0]
    var coors;
    if(event.type === "touchend") {
        coors = {
            x: event.changedTouches[0].pageX,
            y: event.changedTouches[0].pageY
        };
    }
    else {
        // get the touch coordinates
        coors = {
            x: event.touches[0].pageX,
            y: event.touches[0].pageY
        };
    }
    type = type || event.type
    // pass the coordinates to the appropriate handler
    drawer[type](coors);
}

// detect touch capabilities
var touchAvailable = ('createTouch' in document) || ('ontouchstart' in window);

// attach the touchstart, touchmove, touchend event listeners.
if(touchAvailable){
    canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', draw, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', draw, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('touchend', draw, false);        
}    
// attach the mousedown, mousemove, mouseup event listeners.
else {
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', draw, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', draw, false);
}

// prevent elastic scrolling
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}, false); // end body.onTouchMove

}, false); // end window.onLoad
```

Comment: Awesome! That works great! I hadn't though of detecting the touch events that way - I was previously just trying to add the mouse events in addition to the touch events.