# How to change the scrolling function on a Wordpress website?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Working on a Wordpress website, I have been asked to remove something called "non-standard scrolling function" from their website.
check out this page as an example: http://cpmockup.staging.wpengine.com/about/ramp/

It is a bouncing like effect on the page. When you scroll all the way to the bottom of the page it does not stop and it feels like the footer is moving up from its place.(elastic)

I tested it on different browsers, but they show the same result.

Unfortunately, I could not find any option for that on the theme settings. I just wondered if I can add some extra code to fix it. Is that possible? Thank you.

Comment: Your question is *very* vague, you haven't given us much to go on. Are you talking about on mobile? That sort of basic info is important! If it is, do you mean the ***default*** behaviour on mobile browsers? Ask your client for an example of a site where it *doesn't* happen, and let them see for themselves whether its really a "non-standard scrolling function" or not... :)

Comment: Edited my question and added a link as an example.

Comment: That doesn't help anything - you need to tell us *when* and *where* it is happening. Because I can't see what you're talking about if I try Stack Overflow on *desktop*. Unless you meant on mobile... like I asked alreadt in my previous comment. Did you read my comment fully? Is *that* what the problem is?

Comment: sorry. I did. yeah it is a desktop website. I am not sure if it is really a "non-standard scrolling function", but the question is in some websites when you scroll all the way to the end of a page it stops at the footer. In my case when you scroll to the end of the page, browser passes the footer just a little bit and it goes up automatically. It is like the footer bounces. try it for yourself on the link I put in my post.

Comment: Both Stack overflow and your link behave perfectly normally for me on desktop. The only time I've seen the behaviour you describe is on mobile. What browsers are you trying it in? Do you have any extensions that could affect it? If its happening on the SO site for you, it has to be something external.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the problem was inside `custom_js.js`, right? There was code in there that was forcing scroll behavior. For me, it was only apparent when using the mouse wheel. I was going to suggest you remove that code, but upon refreshing the page, it was removed. Was that the issue?

Comment: @JeramiahHarland that wouldn't explain how the OP was seeing this behaviour on the Stack Overflow site though. That's the part that puzzles me.

Comment: Hmmm, good point I missed that comment. @shirin, are you using PC or Mac? I ask because the only natural browser scroll bouncing I can find is related to iOS. That would explain why it happens on other sites, not just the one in question, and why I'm not experiencing it in any browser I've tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ipad safari: disable scrolling, and bounce effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768269/ipad-safari-disable-scrolling-and-bounce-effect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bounce effect is standard behavior in almost all browsers on macOS/iOS (when using trackpad/touch control)

You can minimize it by adding:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

to your CSS. check in DevTools if it is active. If not, add `!important` to override inline CSS from your template..

Comment: "*The bounce effect is standard behavior in almost all browsers.*" - Really?? Because it doesn't happen in *any* of my desktop browsers at all - Chrome, FF, IE11, Edge.

Comment: @FluffyKitten sorry, maybe not on Windows. But on Mac I have it in Chrome and Safari by default on every webpage

Comment: It's definitely standard on iOS on mobile anyway, as I mentioned to the OP in my comments but they said they meant on desktop... maybe they just meant on Mac, because they weren't in the least bit clear in their question when, where or how the problem was happening :)

Comment: It's standard on OS X (desktop) when using a trackpad, but not when using a mouse. I suspect it's largely the same for Windows, where Edge adds a bounce when using a trackpad, but not a mouse.