# how to prevent safari touch event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

When I move to the bottom or the top of the page in safari, I can still swipe it.

I already tried this way:

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', (e) => e.preventDefault());

html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

how to prevent this action? this action will not appear in the chrome, maybe this is the browser behavior?

Comment: I don't have safari to test this, so i will post it as a comment cause i'm not sure. Try using window.touchmove = null;

Comment: is this the same issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768269/ipad-safari-disable-scrolling-and-bounce-effect